# How to get text value from original value is disable

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to get value from read only text box , i tried to get it by `getAttribute` but its return me `null`.

Here is HTML code :

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtStreetNumber" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtStreetNumber" class="inputtxtreadonly" style="width:168px;" originalvalue="" disabled="enable" readonly="readonly">
```

Here is script which i used :

```
WebElement buildingid= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtStreetNumber']"));
System.out.println("Trying to get value "+buildingid.getAttribute("value"));
```

Comment: There is no value attribute in the given HTML, thats why you are getting null. Can you post the url to see the value is populated in text box, may be some js being executed or could be something else.

Comment: Hello , there is no value in url also , ... http://demo.com/Admin/MyProperties.aspx

Comment: Have you tried with getText() method?, if its read only field you should get its value by getText(), Method.

Comment: When I browse url, was redirected to https://www.etouches.com/event-software/ ... can you paste the screenshot .. which page or field you are trying ??

Comment: try..innerHTML, innerText, textContent, value to get value..one of this should fetch you the value

Answer (score 0):

You can use getText() method to get the value of disable element.